# MXGraph: Remote model synchronization; Problem with XML correct xml encoding

Tags: mxgraph

I am trying to synchronize a remote model with local changes.
My idea is to process changes similar to the [graphModel documentation](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/model/mxGraphModel-js.html)

```
function notifyListener(sender, event){
  var codec = new mxCodec();
  var changes = event.getProperty('edit').changes;
  var nodesXml = [];
  
  for (var I=0; I < changes.length; I++) {
    var c = codec.encode(changes[I];
    var cXml = mxUtils.getXml(c);
    nodesXml.push(cXml);
  }
  
};
graph.model.addListener(mxEvent.NOTIFY, notifyListener);
```

However the resulting XML data does only contain a element of ( in case of drag operation) mxGeometryChange;

e.g.

There is no more information; without a reference to the initial cell id I cannot reprocess this xml into the remote model.
I surely miss some information in the xml encoding process; but I don't see it.
Can you help out here ?